# No puedo cambiar el archivo de audio que usa la libreria Winsound

Tags: python, alert

tengo un problema con la libreria Winsound, Intento hacer que cambie el sonido que tiene predeterminado ya que es una alerta muy corta, necesito una mas larga y ruidosa, pero no la cambia. Trato de cambiarla con este codigo, alarm-clock.mp3 es un archivo que tengo en el mismo directorio del programa.

```
#reproducir el sonido
#cambiar el archivo de audio predeterminado
winsound.PlaySound("alarm-clock.mp3", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Qué dice la documentación de la libreria Winsound respecto a cambiar el sonido predeterminado?

Comment: Que con el parametro SND_FILENAME se puede escoger el audio que quiero que suene como alerta, pero es inutil, sigue sonando el predefinido.

Comment: winsound hace el sonido predefinido cuando no encuentra el archivo. Revisaste que el directorio de trabajo tenga el archivo y que el directorio de trabajo sea el mismo que el directorio del archivo de sonido? Podes comprobar estas cosas usando [os.getcwd()](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/os.html#os.getcwd), que devuelve el directorio de trabajo. También revisa que el nombre esté bien escrito.

Comment: Voy a quitar la etiqueta selenium, ya que la pregunta en sí no tiene relación con este.